# How do I return a urllib2 response object from within a Django view?

Tags: python, django, urllib2

I know I can use the shortcuts module to make it easier but just to see if I could do it manually I tried to create and return a response object myself but could not get it to work:

```
import urllib2

def djangoview(request):

    data = '<byte string>'
    open('body.txt', 'wb').write(data)

    headers = {'Content-Type' : 'something', 'Accept' : 'somethingelse'}
    newresponse = urllib2.Request('file:body.txt', None, headers)

    return HttpResponse(newresponse)
```

Comment: Solutions are more helpful than down votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what you are trying to do. It's the contract of a view that it returns an instance of django.http.HttpResponse - you are simply not allowed to return anything else. Doing so is not a shortcut, it's a necessity.

Comment: Right I see, the truth of it is that I'm just learning about urllib2 and was experimenting with it inside or a throwaway django view function. I understand the reason it doesn't work now is because I'm inside of the 'Django container' where it doesn't work. Thank you :)

Comment: Well, not really. urllib2 works fine within Django - it's just Python, after all - but you need to wrap the result in an HttpResponse.